# Creating raster layer from data frame in R?

Tags: r, rasterization

I have created a data frame which I need to convert to an image. This particular data frame is measured 174, 209, 36366 (nrow, ncol, ncell) respectively. This data frame is created and stored in R and I dont know how to export it from R or create a raster layer (of the same dimensions) for imaging from it. 
It is effectively a table of pixel values. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 6):

Coerce the data.frame to a matrix and then use the raster function in the raster library to convert the matrix to a raster. This type of object should be in a matrix format to begin with because you save the overhead of row and column names, which data.frame objects must have.

```
library(raster)

nr = 174
nc = 209
x <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:nr) { x <- rbind(x, runif(nc) ) }

x <- as(x, "matrix")
  dim(x)

x <- raster(x)
  class(x)
  plot(x)
```

From here you can use writeRaster to export to a variety of formats.

Comment: Matrices have also rownames and colnames. one can strip out colnames from dataframes i.e. colnames(df) <- NULL. The point is `raster` only accepts matrix beside other spatial format.

Comment: You cannot get rid of row names in data.frame objects.